# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Deployment failing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ubuntu-16.04, datadog

I have a node.js app already deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. The EC2 instance on which the node app is deployed is running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I am trying to integrate Datadog APM with Elastic Beanstalk using datadog's config file in .ebextensions folder. I am following the instructions given on their docs page(https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/amazon_elasticbeanstalk/#alternate-datadog-agent-configuration)

Even though I am following all the mentioned steps I keep getting the following error on AWS ELB.

[image: ELB error]

My Datadog config file code:

```
# .ebextensions/99datadog.config
option_settings:
    - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name:  DD_API_KEY
    value      :  "MY_API_KEY"
    - namespace:  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name:  DD_AGENT_VERSION
    value      : "7.16.0"
files:
    "/configure_datadog_yaml.sh":
        mode: "000700"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            #!/bin/bash

            DD_KEY="$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k DD_API_KEY)"

            sed 's/api_key:.*/api_key: '$DD_KEY'/' /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml.example > /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml
            echo -e "process_config:\n  enabled: \"true\"\n" >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml

    "/datadog/datadog.repo":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            [datadog]
            name = Datadog, Inc.
            baseurl = https://yum.datadoghq.com/stable/7/x86_64/
            enabled=1
            gpgcheck=1
            gpgkey=https://yum.datadoghq.com/DATADOG_RPM_KEY_E09422B3.public

   "/datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh":
       mode: "000755"
       owner: root
       group: root
       content: |
           #!/bin/bash
           STATUS=`sudo initctl status datadog-agent`
           if [[ "$STATUS" == *"datadog-agent start/running"* ]]
           then
             echo "Agent already running"
           else
             echo "Agent starting..."
             sudo initctl start datadog-agent
           fi

   "/datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh":
       mode: "000755"
       owner: root
       group: root
       content: |
           #!/bin/bash
           STATUS=`sudo initctl status datadog-agent`
           if [[ "$STATUS" == *"datadog-agent stop/waiting"* ]]
           then
             echo "Agent already stopped"
           else
             echo "Agent stopping..."
             sudo initctl stop datadog-agent
           fi


container_commands:
    02mkdir_appdeploy_post:
        test: '[ ! -d /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post ]'
        command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post"
    02mkdir_configdeploy_post:
        test: '[ ! -d /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post ]'
        command: "mkdir /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post"
    10appdeploy_pre_stop:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh ]'
        command: "cp /datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/"
    11appdeploy_post_start:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh ]'
        command: "cp /datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/"
    20preinit_stop:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh ]'
        command: "cp /datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit"
    21postinit_start:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh ]'
        command: "cp /datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postinit"
    30configdeploy_pre_stop:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh ]'
        command: "cp /datadog/hooks/99stop_datadog.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/"
    31configdeploy_post_start:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh ]'
        command: "cp /datadog/hooks/99start_datadog.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/"
    90install_datadog:
        test: '[ -f /datadog/datadog.repo ]'
        command: 'cp /datadog/datadog.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/datadog.repo; yum -y makecache; DD_AGENT_VERSION="$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k DD_AGENT_VERSION)"; yum -y install datadog-agent${DD_AGENT_VERSION:+-$DD_AGENT_VERSION-1}'
    91setup_datadog:
        test: '[ -x /configure_datadog_yaml.sh ]'
        command: "/configure_datadog_yaml.sh"
```

Even after replacing the *initctl* with *systemctl* in the start & stop scripts, I am still getting the same error.

Can't understand where I'm going wrong. Please Help!